# Movie Subtitles

Tags: cinema

Whenever I watch movie with subtitles, I've a feeling of I'm hearing something and reading something else.
With the help of subtitles I can understand the context of the movie well.

But When my purpose is to imitate the dialogue of the characters, I believe subtitles are not solving the purpose.

Are there any videos / movies available with subtitles based on exact pronunciation (even it's informal English) of the characters speak?

Please help me - Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't think this is the place for recommending movies with good subtitles, but you are right: sometimes the subtitle is a paraphrase of what was is said (perhaps to save space). It's unclear whether you mean teaching materials, although I would have thought their subtitles would be exact. Sometimes the subtitles are wrong though, perhaps the author wasn't following the plot well or listening carefully.

Comment: Unlikely. At least not published by the original producers of the movie; subtitles in English are meant to help native speakers who are hard of hearing, not people learning English as a 2nd language. Maybe there’s a 3rd party out there who offers this, bur I’ve never heard of it. Besides, you know the exact pronunciation, you just heard it; it’s nice to be able to map that to spelling, because English spelling is often widely divorced from pronunciation.

Comment: There are videos with verbatim subtitles, e.g. the BBC News does them. You may also find lectures and political speeches done in this manner, but film subtitles are always going to be variable.

Comment: There is always a distinction between the written language and what is pronounced. If you learn the International Phonetic Alphabet, this might help: https://easypronunciation.com/en/ipa-phonetic-subtitle-converters . But I suspect that this automatic translator will translate the written dialogue to IPA, not the actor's pronunciation.

Comment: There are "sing along" movie videos where the subtitles for songs are carefully synchronized to the actors' motions.  "The Sound of Music" is one I recall (though you have to look for the "sing along" version).  As to "normal" subtitling, is varies from fairly exact to quite sloppy.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you're actually *listening to them speak*, you know *exactly* how they're pronouncing their words already. And if you need subtitles in your own language in the first place, then a pronunciation guide being seen at the same time isn't likely to help.

Comment: Often the party making the subtitles does not have access to the script and so makes guesses at the words.